# Firebase cannot get value from Dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve users info from firebase.

```
rk70HDmNSGfugTcIbTdAKhKXE4K2 =     {
    Email = "johnny_bravo770@gmail.com";
    UserID = rk70HDmNSGfugTcIbTdAKhKXE4K2;
    Username = "Johnny_Bravo";
};
```

This is the snapshot I retrieve.
I want to attain the users email but I get a crash due to a nil value

```
func retreiveUsers(){

    databaseRef.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let fetchedUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            print(fetchedUser["Email"])

        }
    })
}
```

What is Wrong?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of ur database structure and show what is databaseRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better if you add more info. I have written in comment.

But I think, that problem is that databaseRef.child("Users") will fetch all users node. You need to add `.child(USER_ID)` or do something like this:

```
databaseRef.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for item in snapshot.children {
        let fetchedUserSnapshot = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
        if let fetchedUser = fetchedUserSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            print(fetchedUser["Email"])
        }      
    }
})
```

Try this

Hope it helps

Comment: Well here you go

Comment: By using your method i got it to work. But i am a real noob at swift and firebase hence, can you describe what is going on.

Comment: @HussainMustafa With .child("Users") you are going to all users node. Not a specific user. So in "for" cycle you are looking over items. Then fetching every user snapshot and getting data from it. Mark it as answer please, so that it could help others

Comment: @HussainMustafa raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2 This is a good tutorial. You can find finished code in the end of the article. Download and look at it. It should help you a lot

Comment: @ VladPulichev Thanks a lot, I have marked your response as an answer. I am new to stack overflow, so i did not know how to mark your response as the answer.

Comment: @HussainMustafa glad to hear. Good luck!:)